# Variable is accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final

Tags: android

I know the topic sounds like a dupplicate, but I am not trying to debug this issue here but to get around it.

What my program is supposed to do is :
For every file there is in a folder, create a new button. If you click on this button, put in the intent extra the name of the folder you've just entered.

```
 File directory = new File(prefs.getString("path",null));
 File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file :files){
            if(file.isDirectory()) {
                buttons.add(new Button(this));
                Button button = buttons.get(buttons.size() - 1);
                String fileName = file.getName();

                button.setText(fileName);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, EOChoiceActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("fileExtension",fileName);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                layout.addView(button);
            }
        }
```

Now the problem I have is that the "fileName" variable needs to be put in final, due to Java giving the pointer of the object and not the value itself. But if I do so, only the last fileName selected will be sent for any button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just go ahead and make `fileName` final. I know you think that this will cause problems, but it won't.

> the "fileName" variable needs to be put in final, due to Java giving the pointer of the object and not the value itself. But if I do so, only the last fileName selected will be sent for any button.

On each iteration through the loop, you're declaring a different `String` instance. Each one will be final, but they will not be "shared" across loop iterations.

I made a tiny app that iterated over an array of `String`s, doing something very similar to your code. Despite declaring my `String` as `final`, each button still toasts a different name when I click it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    final String name = names[i];

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText(name);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    root.addView(button);
}
```

Comment: I went with the idea that declaring a variable final does the same as making the variable global to the class as it was suggested in another topic similar, this is where I got confused. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

No need to declare `fileName` `final`.

Because you are setting `fileName` as text to Button. So use `getText` using `v` parameter of `onClick` to get file name on Button click.like

```
...
intent.putExtra("fileExtension",((Buttton)v).getText().toString());
...
```

Or you can also do it using `setTag()/getTag()` method's of `button` Button.